# Check a mathematical string for syntax errors in Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab, syntax, regular-language, cocor

As an example I have this string: `"12+8*(23+4)*cos(0.813)"` which would be correct. 
In this: `"12+8*)23+4)*co(0.813)"` I should get an error for the first brace ")" and "co".

Is there a way to filter such problems by checking with regular expression or regular language analyser like Coco/R for c#? There you can declare a grammar, tokens etc. and check if a string matches your language.

Only Matlab itself should be used.

Comment: Have you considered looking at a balanced parenthesis check algorithm for arithmetic expressions?  Why do you need to use regular expressions specifically?  The algorithm for balanced parenthesis check is pretty ubiquitous.  Example: http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html - in your case, you're after **infix** expressions.

Comment: It should not just find wrong parenthesis which would be not so difficult to check, but also mathematically not correct spelled operations like: sin(0.56) is ok but siin(0.56) is not correct.

Comment: Ah, so once you figure out whether the parentheses are balanced, then use regular expressions to check if the actual mathematical expressions are correct.  Either way, is there a reason why you need to use MATLAB?

Comment: It is determined to use MATLAB since the rest of the code is matlab-code and no other programm should be used. (If I could use c# i would not have a problem)

Comment: Have you tried [checkcode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html)?

Comment: if this expression is a string, you can use `eval()` function. If the string is not ok, eval will fail.

Comment: You should never use `eval` on random strings (or at all, really). What if somebody decided to input the string `'!rm -rf /'` or something similar?